# How to use buildctl with localhost registry with tls

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry, docker-buildkit, buildkite

Im trying to use buildctl tool with Artifactory registry running on my localhost.

I'm using the following command.

```
buildctl build \
--frontend=dockerfile.v0 \
--local context=. \
--local dockerfile=. \
--output type=image,name=192.168.0.110:8082/docker-local/test,push=true,registry.insecure=true \
--export-cache type=registry,ref=192.168.0.110:8082/docker-local/test,mode=max,push=true,registry.insecure=true \
--import-cache type=registry,ref=192.168.0.110:8082/docker-local/test,registry.insecure=true
```

I added the flag "registry.insecure=true" as stated in the documentation.
but, still getting the following error:

```
> exporting content cache:
------
error: failed to solve: error writing layer blob: failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.0.110:8082/v2/docker-local/test/blobs/sha256:03d1cdba14f373b9dbca6b5fe65f8eca1e9852aaaf9060450b27f924a56a1b3c": remote error: tls: unrecognized name
```

Seems like it's trying to reach the local repo with HTTPS.

### How can I make it work with HTTP?

Using version: buildctl github.com/moby/buildkit 0.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buildkit daemon needs to be run with a configuration file that specifies the registry is http instead of https. See the [documentation on buildkitd.toml](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/docs/buildkitd.toml.md):

```ini
[registry."192.168.0.110:8082"]
  http = true
```

> The file path is `/etc/buildkit/buildkitd.toml` for rootful mode, `~/.config/buildkit/buildkitd.toml` for rootless mode.

Comment: there are no such files on the pod. should i create those?

Comment: @igor probably. It would help to know how you are running buildkitd.

Comment: I'm running as specified in the documentation.
1) export BUILDKIT_HOST=docker-container://buildkit
2) docker run --rm --privileged -d --name buildkit moby/buildkit
3) docker login cloudjtrial.jfrog.io
4) buildctl build ...

Comment: Adding the .toml Worked! thanks